# Express the elements of $\mathbb Z_{\times mod 5} = \{1,2,3,4 \}$ as permutations in cycle form. Hence show that $\mathbb Z_{\times mod 5}$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Am I expected to list all the permutations of $ \{ 1,2,3,4 \} $, 24 in total? And if so, how would I show that its cyclic?

I realised I can show that its cyclic by letting any number from the set $ \{ 2,3,4 \} $ be a generator for the group hence it's cyclic but I wonder what is the original expectation.

Comment: True, there are 24 permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. However, we only care about four of them: The ones given by "multiply by 1", "multiply by 2", "multiply by 3" and "multiply by 4". Those are the ones you are meant to write down in cycle form and analyze.

Answer (score 1):

You consider the group of unities in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(5)=\mathbb{Z}_5$ which is $\mathbb{Z}_5^{*}=\{1,2,3,4\}$ where $1,..,4$ denote the nonzero residue classes modulo $5$ then You get a homomorphism into the symmetric group on four elements by the multiplication tables, e.g. $1$ maps to $()$ and $2$ to $(1243)$, $3$ to $(1342)$ and $4$ to $(14)(23)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: For some reason we cover groups a year before rings at our university ; so I can only work with groups at the moment.

Comment: @Smirniy007 No problem, You just need to understand what is multiplication modulo $5$ for this like $2\cdot 3=1$ etc., i.e. You just have to know what residue classes are and how to multiply them

Answer (score 1):

Consider Cayley's embedding $\theta\colon\mathbb{Z}_5^{\times}\to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}_5^{\times})(=S_4)$, $i\mapsto (j\mapsto ij \pmod 5)$. Then:

$$\theta_1(1)=1, \space \theta_1(2)=2, \space \theta_1(3)=3, \space \theta_1(4)=4$$
$$\theta_2(1)=2, \space \theta_2(2)=4, \space \theta_2(3)=1, \space \theta_2(4)=3$$
$$\theta_3(1)=3, \space \theta_3(2)=1, \space \theta_3(3)=4, \space \theta_3(4)=2$$
$$\theta_4(1)=4, \space \theta_4(2)=3, \space \theta_4(3)=2, \space \theta_4(4)=1$$

or, in disjoint cycle notation:

$$\theta_1=(), \space \theta_2=(1243), \space \theta_3=(1342), \space \theta_4=(14)(23)$$

So we get: $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times \cong \Theta:=\{\theta_i, i=1,2,3,4\}=\langle\theta_2\rangle=\langle\theta_3\rangle$, and $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$ is cyclic with generators $2$ and $3$.